# Parser prefers casting over multiplication

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar

I have been developing a hobby language, and for the past couple days I've been struggling to understand a problem that I've been having. Some aspects of a very stripped-down version of my language are:

- Pointer types
- Struct types (like types, but they are parsed as identifiers)
- Type casting expressions
- Simple math expressions (+, -, *, /, ())
- Evaluation of variables

The grammar has been stripped down for the sole purpose of reproducing this issue, so some things don't make sense (e.g there is no way to assign to a variable). This is the grammar:

```
program =
   expression.e             {: return new Program(e); :};

literal =
    INTEGER_LITERAL.l       {: return new IntegerLiteral(l, false); :};

type =
    normal_type
  | reference_type;

normal_type =
    INT                     {: return new TypeAccess("int"); :};

reference_type =
    type.t MULT             {: return new RefTypeAccess("ref", t); :}
  | id_use.id MULT          {: return new RefTypeAccess("ref", new StructTypeAccess(id.getID())); :};

id_use =
    IDENTIFIER.id           {: return new IdUse(id); :};

primary =
    literal
  | LPAREN.n expression.e RPAREN {: return new ParExpr(e); :};

postfix_expression =
    primary
  | id_use;

unary_expression =
    postfix_expression
  | MULT cast_expression.e                    {: return new DereferenceExpr(e); :};

cast_expression =
    unary_expression
  | LPAREN.n type.t RPAREN cast_expression.e  {: return new CastExpr(t, e); :};

multiplicative_expression =
    cast_expression
  | multiplicative_expression.e1 MULT cast_expression.e2  {: return new MulExpr(e1, e2); :}
  | multiplicative_expression.e1 DIV cast_expression.e2   {: return new DivExpr(e1, e2); :};

additive_expression =
    multiplicative_expression
  | additive_expression.e1 PLUS multiplicative_expression.e2   {: return new AddExpr(e1, e2); :}
  | additive_expression.e1 MINUS multiplicative_expression.e2  {: return new SubExpr(e1, e2); :};

expression =  additive_expression;
```

The grammar is written for the [Beaver](http://beaver.sourceforge.net/) parser generator, but it is pretty similar to BNF. The problem is when I want to parse the following (separately):

```
a * 5   //OK
5 * a   //OK
(a + 1) //OK
(a + 1) //OK
(a * 5) //Syntax error: Unexpected token 5
```

I have managed to narrow it down to the cast expressions. Clearly, when I mean to write a multiplication expression between `a` and `5`, the parser thinks I am instead writing a cast expression to the type `a*` (pointer to struct named `a`). But at this point I am stuck. Why? Taking a look at [C's grammar](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html) specification (which is very similar to mine), there is nothing that significantly differs, and yet that expression parses fine in C.

I am still a grammar noob, but shouldn't this cause some kind of grammar conflict between `multiplicative_expression` and `cast_expression`?

Comment: I don't understand your use of precedence markers, since your grammar doesn't have any precedence relationships declared. Or did you just leave them out, thinking they were not relevant? Please add them so that your problem can be reproduced, or remove the markers. In any case, you should not need precedence resolution for a grammar like this, so it would be interesting to know why they are there.

Comment: Hi. Yes they were left out for clarity. As I mentioned, they're a leftover from a more complicated grammar, which i stripped down in search of a solution. I removed them.

Comment: Also, I dont know how you would reproduce this, but I can share with you the repo of the project. However, my setup is unconventional as it uses Java and Gradle for the build process. The repo is at https://bitbucket.org/JamMaster/statham/src/mwe_cast_error/ in the linked branch

Comment: It's ok. With your change, I just converted it to bison. Bison reports a conflict. Doesn't Beaver?

Comment: It doesn't! Thank you for this tip, I will try Bison as well and take a look! I thought Beaver was mature enough to not have issues like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That grammar has a shift-reduce conflict. I'm not sure why your parser generator doesn't show it.

I converted the grammar to bison (with a small modification at the top-level to make it easier to use in testing). For reference, here's what bison distilled from my input file (which has no precedence declarations):

```
Grammar
    1 program: %empty
    2        | program expression '\n'
    3        | program error '\n'

    4 literal: INTEGER_LITERAL

    5 type: normal_type
    6     | reference_type

    7 normal_type: "int"

    8 reference_type: type '*'
    9               | id_use '*'

   10 id_use: IDENTIFIER

   11 primary: literal
   12        | '(' expression ')'

   13 postfix_expression: primary
   14                   | id_use

   15 unary_expression: postfix_expression
   16                 | '*' cast_expression

   17 cast_expression: unary_expression
   18                | '(' type ')' cast_expression

   19 multiplicative_expression: cast_expression
   20                          | multiplicative_expression '*' cast_expression
   21                          | multiplicative_expression '/' cast_expression

   22 additive_expression: multiplicative_expression
   23                    | additive_expression '+' multiplicative_expression
   24                    | additive_expression '-' multiplicative_expression

   25 expression: additive_expression
```

(See Note 1)

This produced the warning that there is a shift/reduce conflict in state 23:

```
State 23

    9 reference_type: id_use . '*'
   14 postfix_expression: id_use .

    '*'  shift, and go to state 32

    '*'       [reduce using rule 14 (postfix_expression)]
    $default  reduce using rule 14 (postfix_expression)
```

The parser arrives at state 23 via state 7: (Note: I removed most of the goto actions for clarity and space.)

```
State 7

   12 primary: '(' . expression ')'
   18 cast_expression: '(' . type ')' cast_expression

    INTEGER_LITERAL  shift, and go to state 4
    IDENTIFIER       shift, and go to state 5
    "int"            shift, and go to state 19
    '*'              shift, and go to state 6
    '('              shift, and go to state 7

    id_use                     go to state 23
    ...
```

In effect, what's happening is that the parser encounters a parenthesis, and the grammar allows this to either be the start of a parenthesized sub-expression or a cast expression. That's cool; the parser can accept both of the possibilities, which is what is shown in state 7. So it shifts the open parenthesis. At this point, almost any input will resolve the issue of what the parentheses mean, except for an identifier. The identifier might be a typename, or it might name a variable. So the parser continues to explore both possibilities, leading it to state 23.

But here there's a problem if the symbol after the identifier is a `*`, because that will be a multiplication operator if the parentheses are around a sub-expression, and a pointer-creation postfix operator if the parentheses are around a type expression. Since the parser will not know what syntactic form the parentheses take until much later after the closing parenthesis is shifted (and, in fact, possibly not even then as we will see in a moment), it needs to continue to keep both alternatives open. But it cannot, because the grammar now insists that it either reduce the identifier to a `postfix_expression` in one case, or leave it as an identifier in order to integrate it into a `reference_type` in the other case. Since reductions must be taken immediately or never, the parser cannot deal with this uncertainty. Hence the conflict.

Beaver, like bison, will automatically chose to resolve this conflict in favour of the shift. That commits the parser to the parse where the parentheses are the start of a cast expression and the `*` is a postfix pointer type constructor. In the case of `(i*5)` this is not the case, and a syntax error will result. (One more token of lookahead would have been sufficient to resolve this conflict, at least in this simplified grammar. But that might not be the case in a full grammar.)

As you say, C parsers -- which are dealing with a similar grammar -- do not have a problem here. But that's because C parsers have already had to deal with an actual ambiguity in the grammar. In C, the expression `(foo)*(bar)` could be either a multiplication of two variables, or the cast to type `foo` of dereferencing the pointer variable `bar`. The grammar does not provide any mechanism to resolve this ambiguity, but it can easily be resolved if it is known whether `foo` is a typename or not. Since C insists that declaration precede use, that fact must be knowable, although it takes a slightly ugly hack to ensure that the lexical scanner has access to the symbol table being maintained by the parser. (Since type aliases are also subject to scoping rules, the lexical analyser needs to be able to do a full name resolution to make this determination. That adds to the ugliness. But it is still fairly simple.)

Your grammar doesn't seem to suffer from the above ambiguity, since you don't allow casting to a type, only to a pointer to a type. But that doesn't protect you from the shift-reduce conflict with the multiplication/pointer-construction operator `*`. So you still will need to work around the issue, which you could do in the same way as the C compiler.

Of course, another solution is to use a different syntax for casting. You might find the C++ syntax clunky (`reinterpret_cast<int*>(x)`), but it is unambiguous and arguably clearer for someone reading the code. It also serves to discourage the use of casts, which you might or might not feel is a good thing. A less wordy alternative is the `as` operator: `x as int*`, which is used in several scripting languages. (I can't remember a citation off the top of my head, sorry.)

---

#### Notes

1. There is actually no need to have two separate non-terminals, `cast_expression` and `unary_expression`; you can easily combine the two without affecting the grammar:

   ```
   unary_expression: postfix_expression
                   | '(' type ')' unary_expression
                   | '*' unary_expression

   multiplicative_expression: unary_expression
                            | multiplicative_expression '*' unary_expression
                            | multiplicative_expression '/' unary_expression
   ```

   That doesn't solve or worsen the conflict issue, but it does make the grammar slightly simpler.

Comment: Thank you for the awesome answer. Unfortunately, the way my compiler is built, there is no symbol table (at least one that I know of), name analysis is done lazily on the AST as they are needed. But I do think that this casting syntax is confusing, especially considering the example with foo bar. I went with something similar to the c++ way. Also thanks for mentioning bison. The debug printouts are priceless.